# C# Test Will not Compile

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Test Class in Project JohnsonTest

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Usecases;
using Requests;

namespace Controllers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class InitialContollerTest : IUsecase
    {
        private bool executeMethodCalled = false;

        public void Execute(IRequest request)
        {
            executeMethodCalled = true;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ShouldCallInitialUsecase()
        {
            IRequest request = new InitialRequest();
            InitialController controller = new InitialController(request, this);
            controller.Execute();
            Assert.IsTrue(executeMethodCalled);
        }
    }
}
```

Class under test in Project Johnson

```
using Requests;
using Usecases;

namespace Controllers
{
    interface IController
    {
        void Execute();
    }

    public class InitialController : IController
    {
        private IUsecase usecase;
        private IRequest request;

        public InitialController(IRequest request, IUsecase usecase)
        {
            this.request = request;
            this.usecase = usecase;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            usecase.Execute(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Other Classes involved in Project Johnson

```
using Requests;

namespace Usecases
{
    public interface IUsecase
    {
        void Execute(IRequest request);
    }

    public class InitialUsecase : IUsecase
    {
        public void Execute(IRequest request)
        {
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace Requests
{
    public interface IRequest
    {
    }

    public class InitialRequest : IRequest
    {
    }
}
```

The build errors are:

> 1>C:\Users\bggib_000\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Johnson\Johnson\JohnsonRibbon.cs(25,21,25,38): error
>   CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
>   formal parameter 'usecase' of
>   'InitialController.InitialController(IRequest, IUsecase)'

This seems to be complaining about 'this', but my previous test with just 'this'

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Usecases;

namespace Controllers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class InitialContollerTest : IUsecase
    {
        private bool executeMethodCalled = false;

        void IUsecase.Execute()
        {
            executeMethodCalled = true;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ShouldCallInitialUsecase()
        {
            InitialController controller = new InitialController(this);
            controller.Execute();
            Assert.IsTrue(executeMethodCalled);
        }


    }
}
```

worked with this Class:

```
public class InitialController : IController
    {
        IUsecase usecase;

        public InitialController(IUsecase usecase)
        {
            this.usecase = usecase;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            usecase.Execute();
        }
    }
```

> 2>C:\Users\bggib_000\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Johnson\JohnsonTest\ContollerTest.cs(8,41,8,49): error
>   CS0535: 'InitialContollerTest' does not implement interface member
>   'IUsecase.Execute()'

This seems to be complaining about something that does not exist.

```
using Requests;

namespace Usecases
{
    public interface IUsecase
    {
        void Execute(IRequest request);
    }

    public class InitialUsecase : IUsecase
    {
        public void Execute(IRequest request)
        {
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio Community 2017 does not indicate any errors. Why wont this compile?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: [MCVE] please.  ..

Comment: The `InitialController` constructor expects two arguments, you provide one.

Comment: @rory.ap alright. something new I've learnt today ;).

Comment: @CodeCaster In the current test I am passing two arguments InitialController controller = new InitialController(request, this);

Comment: Sorry to bother the community with this question. Rookie mistake. I am new to VS and missed it was complaining about at different file: JohnsonRibbon.cs, and sure enough in that file I was calling InitialController with one argument. Once I added an argument for the Request it compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file was the problem:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Controllers;

namespace Johnson
{
    public partial class JohnsonRibbon
    {
        private void JohnsonRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void OnInitalButtonClick(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            string Prompt = "Select two data columns (X, Freq) for analysis";
            string Title = "Select Histogram";
            var range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.InputBox(Prompt: Prompt, Title: Title, Type: 8);
            if (range is Excel.Range)
            {
                new InitialController(new Usecases.InitialUsecase()).Execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once I changed this line

```
new InitialController(new Usecases.InitialUsecase()).Execute();
```

to this it worked

```
new InitialController(new Requests.InitialRequest(), new Usecases.InitialUsecase()).Execute();
```